# MS Access - Update specific values of one table based on values from another table (Field Length Specific)

Tags: ms-access

One table has address field with example values:

```
123 Main Street Professional Center
456 Avenue Of Americas Financial Square
678 Great Northern Boulevard University Centre
```

These values exceed certain number of characters (in this case- field length of 30)

I have another table that has values and their USPS approved acronyms:

```
Field1    Acronym
Street    St
Boulevard Blvd
Square    Sq
```

I would like to be able to update street column in my first table with acronyms from second table, based on matched values in Field1 in my second table.

Possible? Alternate solutions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is itereate for each record in the acronyms table. Then, replace the matching value.

```
Public Sub UpdateTable()
Dim rs  As Recordset
Dim sql As String
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("acronyms")
    Do Until rs.EOF
        sql = "UPDATE addresses SET address = Replace([address], '" & rs!Field1 & "', '" & rs!Acronym & "') WHERE address like '*" & rs!Field1 & "*'"
        CurrentDb.Execute sql
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Clone
End Sub
```

Note: Depending on the ms-access version, the like expression should be with * or with %

Comment: Good answer. However, the difference in wildcard characters is not a function of the version of Access, it depends on where the query is being executed. Queries run from within the Microsoft Access application itself use `*` as the wildcard for "zero or more characters", while queries run from external applications (connecting via ADO, OLEDB, etc.) use `%` as the wildcard.

Comment: With different version of access I refered to mdb/adp files. From Access 2003, project files (adp) use % wildcard, meanwhile normal access databases is an option that you can set in Options->Tables/Queries->SQL Syntax
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-projects-and-data-access-pages-now-use-ansi-sql-92-syntax-HA001034562.aspx
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/comparison-of-microsoft-jet-sql-and-ansi-sql-HP001032250.aspx